# loop through nested object javascript

Tags: javascript, nested-object

I am trying to loop through a following nested object and get an output as below:

```
const preference = {
    "ethnicity": {
        "value": "Newar",
        "rank": 1
    },
    "occupation": {
        "value": "Banker",
        "rank": 2
    }
}
```

I tried following:

```
let preferenceRank = {};
preference.map(pref => {
  preferenceRank[pref.rank] = pref; 
});

console.log(preferenceRank);
```

I get this error:

```
"TypeError: preference.map is not a function"...
```

Output required:

```
{
  1: "ethnicity",
  2: "occupation",
}
```

Comment: convert the object into an array and use the map method.

Comment: `map` is an array function. You can use `Object.keys()` to iterate the keys and then get your rank values by `preference[key]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get keys and values at once (as array of arrays `[key, value]`):

```js
const preference = {
    "ethnicity": {
        "value": "Gurung",
        "rank": 1
    },
    "occupation": {
        "value": "Banker",
        "rank": 2
    }
}

const preferenceRank = {}
for (const [key, { rank }] of Object.entries(preference)) {
    preferenceRank[rank] = key
}

console.log(preferenceRank)
```

(By the way, in your code it doesn't make any sense to use `map` there, since you are not mapping the array to anything, and you ignore the return value of `map`. You probably wanted `forEach` instead or, as I used now, a `for` loop.)

---

#### 2021 Update

There is now an easier way widely available, using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), which does the opposite of `Object.entries`, thereby allowing us to express the whole thing as a `map`ping operation:

```js
const preferenceRank = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(preference).map(([key, { rank }]) => [rank, key])
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) function to map over the object.

```js
Object.entries(preference).reduce((out, [key, value]) => {
  out[value.rank] = key;
  return out;
},{});
```

Comment: It could be simplified to `.reduce(out, [key, { rank }]) => Object.assign(out, { [rank]: key }), {})`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Object.entries()` to get an array of the keys and values of the object. You can then loop over that.

Use `forEach` if the loop is being done for side effect rather than using the values returned by the callback function.

```js
const preference = {
    "ethnicity": {
        "value": "Gurung",
        "rank": 1
    },
    "occupation": {
        "value": "Banker",
        "rank": 2
    }
}

let preferenceRank = {};
Object.entries(preference).forEach(([pref, {rank}]) => {
  preferenceRank[rank] = pref; 
});

console.log(preferenceRank);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could map the entries and build a new object.

```js
const
    preference = { ethnicity: { value: "Gurung", rank: 1 }, occupation: { value: "Banker", rank: 2        } },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(preference)
        .map(([k, { rank }]) => [rank, k])
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

```
const preferenceRank = {};
Object.keys(preference).forEach((key) => {
  preferenceRank[preference[key]['rank']] = preference[key]['value'];
});

console.log(preferenceRank);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could map over the keys and add to a result-object the rank/key-objects.

```js
const preference = {
    "ethnicity": {
        "value": "Gurung",
        "rank": 1
    },
    "occupation": {
        "value": "Banker",
        "rank": 2
    }
}

let res= {};
Object.keys(preference).map((el,key) => {
    res[preference[el].rank] = el;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

map only works for arrays, you are dealing with an object, what you can is go through the keys of the objects by using

```
Object.keys(preference)
```

this will return to you the object keys in an array as the following
["ethnicity","occupation"]

then you can map through it if you want and do your code

Answer (score 0):

```
const preference = {
    "ethnicity": {
        "value": "Gurung",
        "rank": 1
    },
    "occupation": {
        "value": "Banker",
        "rank": 2
    }
}
console.log({...Object.keys(preference)})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).